# Accessing file in resource/static folder of Spring Boot from war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath, war

I have a Spring Boot application deployed as war file on server .

I am trying to access a .txt file located at `src\main\resources\static\sql_collection\configure_SQL_Descriptions.txt` from within the code

Everything works fine when I run the war file on local Spring Boot embedded tomcat but when I deploy it on my organization server, it outputs error NoSuchFileException.

I have read many post on internet that if you would like to load a file from classpath in a Spring Boot JAR/war, then you have to use the `resource.getInputStream()`.

I tried many steps like :-

```
 Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");


ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("fileName").getFile());
```

etc etc

but every time each trial fails and it says file doest not exist at location. I use this path: `src\main\resources\static\sql_collection\configure_SQL_Descriptions.txt` as string for every option I explored.

Comment: Can you confirm the file is inside the war file?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes it is inside the war

Comment: Do not use backslashes when searching for resources in ZIP files or web archives. I do not know if this caused the error, but it is worth a try. Additionally, please add the actual code you tried to your question, not something like "filename".